# from webdriver-manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager ошибка!

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, pytest

При попытке импортировать
`from webdriver-manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`
редактор подчеркивает красным webdriver-manager
[image: то как это выглядит]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно импортировать webdriver-manager через терминал командой `pip install webdriver-manager` потом уже можно прописывать `from webdriver-manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` в файле.